# SQL query to find top n values for a column for a specific type of data set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have with me some data - Sales data for different companies for different years.
So I have company `ID`, `Year` and `Sales` of that company (for that year).

What I want is to obtain the `TOP n` values of sales, and corresponding company `ID` and `Year`, for each company that has data.

There are other queries in SO but they are for straight forward `TOP n` values for a single column (without conditions like the one required here).

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 5):

You probably need something like this:

```
select
    CompanyName,
    Year,
    Sales

from (
    select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by CompanyName order by Sales desc) as RowNbr 

    from data) src

where RowNbr <= 5

order by CompanyName, Sales desc
```

Just replace 5 with whatever number you like.

Answer (score 3):

If you are SQL 2005+, the `CTE` approach will work:

```
WITH salesWithRank AS
(
   SELECT CompanyID, Year, Sales
      , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CompanyId ORDER BY Sales DESC) AS RowNumber
   FROM SalesData
)
SELECT CompanyID, Year, Sales
FROM salesWithRank AS s
WHERE RowNumber <= 10 -- Top 10 sales for each CompanyId, any year
ORDER BY CompanyId ASC, Sales DESC
```

Note, if you have CompanyName in the table, you could use that to Order by as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just going straight forward:

```
SELECT TOP 3 CompanyID, Year, Sales
FROM (SELECT CompanyID, Year, Sales, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CompanyID ASC,Sales DESC) AS RowNumber 
      FROM TargetTbl) AS TempTable
ORDER BY RowNumber ASC
```

EDIT: replace 3 with your desired value of n(top number of rows).

Comment: -1. This will not retrieve the last X years for all companies, it will retrieve the highest X sales years across all companies. Some companies could be duplicated, some could be excluded.

Comment: Hello @AdamRobinson, how "SELECT CompanyID, Year, Sales, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CompanyID ASC,Sales DESC) AS RowNumber FROM TargetTbl" exclude some rows, though this may include some duplicate data but it is not part of the question.
The asker is asking top N data without condition and "TOP n values of sales" is part of the question that mean he wants sales DESC ordered. Would you please review again, thanks for your time.

Comment: The OP wants the top N sales years *for each company*. Your SQL will give the top N sales years regardless of company (i.e. Company A could have all 5 slots). Your query is functionally equivalent to `select top N CompanyID, Year, Sales from TargetTbl order by CompanyID, Sales desc`.

Comment: @AdamRobinson, you're right, so its better to have partition by company ID (CompanyName), thanks for your time.